# highlight and write a tag to textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Textbox on a form. I Want to highlight the textbox and write a tag in the bottom of the text box in javascript. i am doing the following to get the value,

```
var form = getAdjustedForm(obj, modelKey);
var reasonText = document.getElementById("AlertSuppression_Reason").value;

if (reasonText == "" || reasonText.length == 0 || reasonText == null) {         
    $('#AlertSuppression_Reason').text("This Trade will be updated.");
    document.getElementById('AlertSuppression_Reason').style.borderColor  = "red";      
}
```

With this the textbox is turning red but its not writing a tag. I want something like:

[image]

Comment: it could be better if you can post html code even...

Comment: var section = form.addSection();section.addSegment().setColumnCount(1).addRow("Reason")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a text container, like `span`, that's gonna be hidden by default. Then you need to add an event listener like `onkeyup` to the textbox that's gonna detect its value's length, if the textbox is empty, then display the text.

Example in pure JS:

https://jsfiddle.net/9tbj2gw6/

Comment: Can we add a span to the textbox in javascript?

Comment: Not to the textbox directly, but to the same container as the textbox is in, like div - parent, textbox and span - children. It's better to just keep the span statically in the HTML and just show/hide it when necessary.

Comment: How to do it if its a calender date picker? I need to show the span if the selected date is greater than one year from today.

Comment: Textbox: var jqField = $(getObjectById("AlertSuppression_Reason".replaceAll("\\.", "_")));
   jqField.addClass("input-validation-error");
   var span = jqField.parent().find(".field-validation-valid");
   span.addClass("field-validation-error");
   span.html("Reason is a required field");
   span.toggle(true);
 
   jqField.bind("focus", function () {
    this.oldValue = this.value;
   }).blur(function () {
    if (this.oldValue != this.value) {
    jqField.removeClass("input-validation-error");
    span.removeClass("field-validation-error");
    span.html("");
     } 
    });